# How to choose proper radius for a map in leaflet?

Tags: r, leaflet, icons, scale, radius

I'm trying to make a map by leaflet in R. The attribute data as radius for the circle is discrete from 1 to 3500. I use simple way to scale it:

```
radius = Points$attribute/100
```

but as the figure shows, some cities are too large to overlap, while some are too small.

is there any nice way to scale data for the radius?

[image]

Comment: If you want to represent an attribute as an area, then use the square root of that attribute as the radius. Also, consider making symbols transparent so they can overlap visibly.